# Notation for each point in Cartesian product

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I am struggling with mathematical notation for an algorithm I am describing.

Say I have $n$ variables. For each variable $i=[1,...,n]$ we choose a set of $q^i$ points:
$$X^i= \{ x^i_1,x^i_2,...,x^i_{q^i} \}$$

The combination of all possible points is the cartesian product:
$$\mathscr{X}=X^{1}\times\ldots\times X^{n}$$
which consists of $m=\prod_{i=1}^{n}q^{i}$ points.

Next we have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, which we want to evaluate for given parameters $\theta$, so $f\left(\boldsymbol{x};\theta\right)$.

We want to evaluate the function at the set of points in the cartesian product, and minimize the squared sum. The problem is I don't know what notation to use for the points in the cartesian product. I can only think of something like:

$$\min_{\theta}\sum_{j=1}^{m}f\left(\boldsymbol{x}_j;\theta\right)^{2}$$

with $m$ being the total number of points in set $\mathscr{X}$ and $\boldsymbol{x}_j$ referring to each point in that set.

What would be the clear and correct notation for this?

Comment: Why not just $\min_\theta \sum \limits_{x \in \cal X} f(x,\theta)^2$? It is a finite sum, since $\cal X$ is finite so the order doesn’t really matter…

Comment: That is a good idea!

Comment: I have a follow up question. There is one algorithm where each element in the set $\mathcal{X}$ (ie. the Cartesian product) has a specific value $\theta$.

So for every element $x_i$ in the set $\mathcal{X}$ there is $\theta_i$ which solves the equation $0=f(x_i,\theta_i)$.

How would you write down that system of equations?

Comment: Well I don’t know which equation you mean, but if each $x \in \cal X$ comes with its own theta you can denote this theta by $\theta_x$ or if you don’t like subscripts of arbitrary sets $\theta(x)$, where $x \mapsto \theta(x)$ is the function assigning each $x$ its corresponding theta…

Comment: Cool! Thanks again!